# Decimal TO Binary in Dataframe Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, binary, decimal

I have a dataset and trying to read by Pandas dataframe. I want to transform one of the columns decimal values to binary. I have three columns and want the values of second column to be changed to binary. I have tried `format(n, 'b')` function like below but doesn't work out! Can anyone tell me what should I do?

```
df = pd.read_csv('health.csv', header=None)
format( health.iloc[:,1], 'b')
```

The error I am getting is like this:

```
ValueError: Unknown format code 'b' for object of type 'str'
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are the values currently contained in that column?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "convert to binary"? You want them to be string representations of binary numbers?

Comment: You probably want `health[colName].apply(lambda x: format(int(x), 'b'))`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I assume so, format will return a string representation.

Comment: @Ksofiac It contains integer values and i want to convert them to binary!

Comment: Check how you're importing your data into the pandas dataframe - and explicitly set that column to integer

Comment: @user8034918 I really wish you'd post your data.

Answer (score 0):

you want to use :

```
Health.Col.apply(lambda x: format(int(x), '04b'))
```

where `Col` is the column name you want to convert.

the thing is format doesn't work on strings so you need to convert your inputs to integers before getting their binary string representation ('04b' is just to have the representation on 4 bits).

example:

```
   A  B
0  a  1
1  a  2
2  a  3
3  a  4

df['C'] = df.B.apply(lambda x: format(int(x), '04b'))

#   A  B     C
#0  a  1  0001
#1  a  2  0010
#2  a  3  0011
#3  a  4  0100
```

I believe this is what you're looking for.

Comment: I don't have any string on the column even the column has no name! and the values in the columns are integers and i want to convert them to binary which is combination of zeros and ones!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

`health.iloc[:,1].astype(int).map('{:b}'.format)`